# understanding the bundle metric

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, vector-bundles

I came across the following definition online;
[image]

I am curious to know if the vector bundle being smooth would imply that the metric is smooth? Can this be proved or maybe disproved with a counter example? Thank you!

Comment: With the charts definitions as isometries, the metric on the bundle is the pull-back of the euclidean metric on $\Bbb R^k$, thus as smooth as the charts maps of the atlas.